# ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)

Tags: python, sockets, ssl

**When I test crl revoke with python ssl and socket**

When I try to use the python crl file to check whether the peer certificate is revoked,
I consulted the official python documentation, but there was very little.
My basic steps:

1. Convert the .crl file to a .pem file.
2. Invoke the python ssl.load_verify_location interface.

```
def tls_check(domain, port):
    addr = domain
    ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
    ctx.options &= ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
    ctx.verify_flags = ssl.VERIFY_CRL_CHECK_CHAIN
    ctx.check_hostname = False
    ctx.load_verify_locations(cafile="/home/linux/CloudBrahma_release/Utils/pre_crl.pem")
    sock = ctx.wrap_socket(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM), server_hostname=addr)
    sock.connect((addr, port))
    print("TLS Ceritificate:")
    pprint.pprint(sock.getpeercert())
    print("TLS Version:", sock.version())
    print("TLS Cipher:", sock.cipher()[0])
    exit()
tls_check("xxxxx", 8080)
```

i got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 28, in <module>
    tls_check("100.94.2.17", 8443)
  File "test.py", line 21, in tls_check
    sock.connect((addr, port))
  File "/home/linux/py3env/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1150, in connect
    self._real_connect(addr, False)
  File "/home/linux/py3env/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1141, in _real_connect
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/home/linux/py3env/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1117, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> ctx.load_verify_locations(cafile="/home/linux/CloudBrahma_release/Utils/pre_crl.pem")
> ```

This is expecting a file with the trusted CA. If you give a file with CRL instead you essentially have no trusted CA. This means it will not be able to find the root CA for a certificate since you have no trusted root CA defined, resulting in

> ```
> ... certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)
> ```

Instead the given `cafile` must include the trusted root CA **and additionally** the CRL if you want to check for CRL. But granted, this kind of API is strange and the documentation is not really helpful either.

Comment: First of all thank you very much
I don’t quite understand why cafile needs to include crt and crl files
I tested it
1. `cafile=(crt_path, crl_path)` Obviously this is useless
2. I merged the two certificates into one certificate, it doesn’t work either

Comment: @createbugofmaster: `cafile` is the name of a file, not a tuple or list or so. This file must contain the trusted root CA and it can optionally contain the CRL - just append all the PEM from CA certificates and CRL. *"I merged the two certificates into one certificate,"* - I have no idea what exactly you did and what the result was so I cannot say what you did wrong here. Not enough details to reproduce it.